# Null pointer when accessing private data of device driver from other device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing a module which works as a layer between mac80211 module and ath9k device driver (I have done that by exporting ath9k_ops, then accessing it in my module and changing the callback functions in order to point to functions in my module).

For now, my module just intercepts mac80211 callback operations (by `struct ieee80211_ops`) and forward them to the device driver.

Part of `struct ieee80211_ops` is:

```
struct ieee80211_ops {
    void (*tx)(struct ieee80211_hw *hw, struct ieee80211_tx_control *control, struct sk_buff *skb);
    /* other callback functions ... */
}
```

This way, when module 80211 calls  callback function `(*tx)` I can access members of the structs `ieee80211_hw`, `ieee80211_tx_control`, `sk_buff`, except the pointer pointing to private data of the device:

```
    struct ath_softc *sc = hw->priv;
```

What I am not following is that the original callback function of the ath9k device driver (which I call at the end of my callback function) does exactly the same thing:

```
static void ath9k_tx(struct ieee80211_hw *hw,
         struct ieee80211_tx_control *control,
         struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    struct ath_softc *sc = hw->priv;
    /* other code accessing members of struct ath_softc normally */
}
```

So, why can't my module access the private data and ath9k module can? `hw->`

I think I provided enough information regarding the problem because the issue is *probably related to the way private data is protected from other modules accessing it*, and it's my fault in not understanding how memory fully works in linux kernel.

Thank you very much. Let me know if it's worth to provide more information on the question.

Comment: This should work based on my experience under normal circumstances.

When I've seen problems like this in the past, it is because the sizes of the structures do not match due to options or alignment. How are you building your module?  Can you verify that the the offset of the `priv` member of `struct ieee80211_hw` is the same in both your module and the original module?

Comment: sruffell, you pointed in the right direction. I solved the problem after checking the struct sizes. When I compiled my module there was a definition which changed the size of the struct comparing to the size of the same struct compiled by the kernel itself. Then, I was trying to access a unaligned member of the struct and therefore it was null. Thank you!